# Bootstrap3 btn-group-justified not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do this:
[image]

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Proveedor</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

But "btn-group-justified" seems to be not working.

I have tried also this way:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Proveedor</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It seems like "btn-group-justified" is not working.

Any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-justified-90">Proveedor</a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

And adding this style in another css file:

```
.btn-justified-90{
    display: table;
    width: 90%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this to your css file at the end.

```
.btn-group-justified{
width:100%;
}
```